# What does the pair of equations $y=3$ and $z=5$ represent in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $x$ is not held constant?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is $(x,3,5)$ a plane, for $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

I know that if two of the coordinates are "arbitrary", like $(x,y,4)$or $(3,y,z)$, then it creates a plane (for $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}).$

Is there a way to tell if it would create a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3?$

Comment: Your question is odd: $\;(x,3,5)\;$ is a vector, it can't be a plane, so what did you **really** mean to ask?

Comment: I think he means that he is looking at a point where the x is variable, but the y and z are not. But yes, notation wise, it could be a vector and then my answer isn't right.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Sorry for any confusion- I meant what does the pair of equations $y=3$ and $z=5$ represent in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $x$ is not held constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $y=3$ defines a line in $\mathbb R^2$, but a plane in $\mathbb R^3$. Likewise $z=5$ defines a plane in $\mathbb R^3$. Each equation can be seen as constraining a point in one dimension, leaving it free to be located in a two-dimensional space (in this case a plane).

The two equations $y=3, z=5$ taken together define the intersection between the two planes, which is a line (this always happens with two planes in $\mathbb R^3$, except in the case where the planes are parallel). A third equation would identify a particular point on the line (except in special cases).

This is very much akin to the way in which two straight lines in the plane intersect in a single point unless they are parallel.

Note that each equation reduces the dimension by $1$ - we start with $\mathbb R^3$ - with one equation we get to a plane, two equations gives us a line and three give a point. This counting-down principle also applies in greater numbers of dimensions (noting always that we have to exclude special cases).

Answer (score 3):

The subset $$\{(x,3,5):x \in \mathbb{R}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$$ is not a plane.  It is an affine space, a translation of the vector space $$\{(x,0,0):x \in \mathbb{R}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$$ which has dimension $1$.  A plane has dimension $2$.  So, by the [Dimension Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces), it cannot be a plane.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. It is a line in space parallel to the x-axis. Graph the points (-1,3,5) , (0,3,5) , (1,3,5) , (2,3,5) etc. What do you notice?